# Form not working on index page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I'm using Spring 3 and Eclipse. The weirdest thing happened, when I was trying to make a form on index page: all I got is neither plain target or binding result for bean name (commandname) error...but when I copy EXACTLY THE SAME form to other .jsp-file and THE SAME controller method, it works fine! Can anyone tell what it is?

Answer (score 0):

The request from your "index page" is obviously bypass somehow your spring front controller.